# List of nodes in a AVL binary search tree, ordered by their height

Tags: algorithm, sorting, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, avl-tree

What is the best way (computationally) to get a list of nodes in a AVL tree sorted by their height?
For example with an AVL like this:
[image: Example]

The output should be:

[A, C, G, O, B, N, H, D]

(No matter the order in case there are nodes of the same height)

Comment: In what way is the output you list "sorted", when `O` appears before `H`, but after `G`?

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis I was wondering the same thing at first but then I realized that they are indeed correct. The `height` of a node is defined as the maximum depth of its children. A, C, G and O have height=0. B and N have height=1, H have height=2  and D have height=3.

Comment: Ugh, I confused "height" with "depth" for whatever reason, thanks @EmilVikström

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis Me too, and I am working with trees *right now* in my day job. I even wrote a getHeight function just a few hours ago.

Comment: Traverse the tree from leaves up using BFS. Make use of balance indicator of each node.

Answer (score 0):

You can do any of the `inorder`, `postorder` or `preorder` traversals and calculate the height of each node. But for this problem instead of just calculating we insert the nodes in the data structure very similar to `adjacency list`, the only difference being now `linked list` at `position 0` stores all the nodes with `height = 0`, `linked list` at `position 1` stores all the nodes with `height = 1`, and so on.

To get the output, we could simply print the elements each linked list starting from the first `linked list`.

Following simple pseudocode does the job:

```
void inorderTraversal(NodePointer ptr)
{
 if(ptr == NULL)
  return;
 else
 {

  inorderTraversal(ptr->left);
  if(ptr->left == NULL and ptr->right == NULL)
  {
   ptr->height = 0;
   adjacencyList[ptr->height].append(ptr->value);
  }
  else
  {
   if(ptr->left != NULL and ptr->right == NULL)
   {
    ptr->height = ptr->left->height + 1;
    adjacencyList[ptr->height].append(ptr->value);
   } 
   if(ptr->right != NULL and ptr->left == NULL)
   {
    ptr->height = ptr->right->height + 1;
    adjacencyList[ptr->height].append(ptr->value);
   } 
   if(ptr->right != NULL and ptr->left != NULL)
   {
    h1 = ptr->left->height;
    h2 = ptr->right->height;
    ptr->height = max(h1,h2)
    adjacencyList[ptr->height].append(ptr->value);    
   }    
  }   
  inorderTraversal(ptr->right);
 }  
}
```

Now we can simply traverse all the `linked lists`  starting from the first `linked list` and get the nodes in ascending order of their height.

Comment: This will work, but requires a data structure for `adjacencyList` with constant-time search. I think your approach is unnecessarily complex.

Comment: @EmilVikström Suppose that in the given tree of OP, you do not have nodes A and C. Then both nodes B and O have height 0. But their levels are different.

Comment: @EmilVikström Level of B becomes 1 and level of O is 3. Because BFS traverses the tree level by level, bfs would not print B and O together.

Comment: @EmilVikström The two nodes would be separated by nodes of level 2 in your data structure R.

Comment: Wouldn't that create an unbalanced AVL tree? But you seem to be correct anyway, [this balanced AVL tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:AVL-tree-wBalance_K.svg) would give incorrect output with my algorithm. I wonder if you can use the balancing property to tweak the BFS approach, though?

Comment: @EmilVikström I agree that would indeed create invalid avl tree.

Comment: @EmilVikström But a simple bfs would not work, like u said.